# C\C++ Preprocessor different arg for overloaded macros

Tags: macros, c-preprocessor

I want to realize logging in my project.
I have macro, smth like

```
__LOG_TRACE(lg, expr,...) LOG_TRACE_STREAM(lg) << expr;
```

So I want to realize interface for this macro - another macro, but I want to support 2 types:

```
LOG_TRACE(msg);
LOG_TRACE(my_logger, msg);
```

I have some global logger, and first macro will write `msg` using global logger.
Second macro will take `my_logger` and write `msg` using it.

I can make it with `LOG_TRACE(msg, my_logger);` - but it's not good, it's harder to read in code. Order of arguments in `__LOG_TRACE` is not necessary.

Upd:
I don't mean overloading macros. 
Look - for example I can do this

```
#define LOG_TRACE(...) __LOG_TRACE(__VA_ARGS__, current_active)
```

Now I can write

```
LOG_TRACE(msg);
LOG_TRACE(msg, logger);
```

But I want not `msg,logger` and `logger,msg`

Comment: What is the exact requirement ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Macro overloading is not allowed in C or C++. But there are workarounds. Here's an article that will help you "overload" your macro: http://cplusplus.co.il/2010/08/31/overloading-macros/

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have a variable number of loggers, i recommend you to make a macro for each logger. ex (LOG_TRACE_XML, LOG_TRACE_OUT, LOG_TRACE_TXT). Because simpler is better.

But a better way to do this is to have LOG_TRACE_ERROR/ LOG_TRACE_WARNING/ LOG_TRACE_INFO and manage the way these macros behave using IPC or another macro (SET_MODE(XML/TXT/OUT))

Comment: I have just 7 loggers - but problem is old code - i have to much of old code, where used LOG_TRACE(msg); - and i couldn't lose compatibility.

Comment: maybe the solution is a layer that unifies everything. Or code refactoring and keep only one logger. Anyway it's a big depends on implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot overload pre-processor macros, your compiler will consider this a redeclaration, rather than an overload, and so only the 2nd will be valid.

You should attempt to name your macros differently, both for readability and because that's the only way you'll get the functionality you want.

Comment: I don't mean overloading of macro - i want some "game" with __VA_ARGS__

Answer (score 0):

Why not make it a function + do and stringify expression macro?

```
#define DO_AND_RETURN_STRING_EXPR(x) (x,#x)

ov(DO_AND_RETURN_STRING_EXPR(y))
ov(my_logger, DO_AND_RETURN_STRING_EXPR(y))
```

(note I haven't tested this code).

Answer (score 0):

`__VA_ARGS__` is an extension to the current C++ standard, but if you are willing to play with this [P99](http://p99.gforge.inria.fr) has a lot of utility macros to achieve what you want. In particular macros that implement conditionals according to the number of arguments they are called.

```
#define LOG_TRACE(...)                    \
P99_IF_EQ_1(P99_NARG(__VA_ARGS__))        \
(LOG_TRACE_(my_logger, __VA_ARGS__))      \
(LOG_TRACE_(__VA_ARGS__))
```

P99 is not really C++ compatible, so you'd have to adapt things a bit.

BTW, identifiers that start with `_` and a capital letter or another underscore are reserved by C and C++. Double underscores in general are not allowed for C++ because they could interfere with name mangling. So you'd better chose a different name for your base macro.